# How to track mouse dragging?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

What event do I need to write in my wxWidgets program so that I can track mouse dragging.
I mean hold down the left mouse button and track the movement while it is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Bind(wxEVT_MOTION, [&](wxMouseEvent& event) {
    if (event.Dragging()) {
        if (event.LeftIsDown()) {
            // code
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that `event.Dragging` does not differentiate between left and right buttons.

Comment: @macroland 
yes but you can see which button is pressed through the mouse event functions.The LeftIsDown function is one of them.

Comment: Yes, I think now the answer is more to the point! Btw, you can easily combine event.Dragging with event.LeftIsDown to one line.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps surprisingly, this is not such a simple task. You may look at the implementation of [wxMouseEventsManager](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.2/classwx_mouse_events_manager.html) to see an example of working code doing it, but the main point is that you need to capture the mouse on button press, in order to follow its movement even if it exits the window, and then you need to also react to `wxEVT_MOUSE_CAPTURE_LOST` events to know when the capture is forcibly broken.